# Executing a outgoing/incoming call broadcast receiver in android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, broadcastreceiver, terminal-emulator

I have written a simple BroadcastReceiver application in Android to monitor the incoming and outgoing calls... i would like test the BroadcastReceiver via emulator... can anyone please let me know how to execute the BroacastReceiver in emulator??

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Emulator Control View in Eclipse. This user interface allows you to send data to the emulator to emulate receiving an SMS message or phone call. 
Run the application in the emulator, and go to Window -> Show View -> Other -> Android -> Emulator Control.
Enter incoming number and choose Voice option for call and SMS option for SMS.